# How do I refresh data from SQL server into PHP page at intervals using AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How do I use AJAX to get new data from "temperatur" every few minutes and update that number only, in the webpage without refreshing the page?

Part of index.php

```php
        <!-- Top Container -->
    <section class="top-container">
        <div class="top-box top-box-a">
            <p class="values"><i class="fas fa-thermometer-three-quarters"></i><br>
                <?php 
                    include 'sql_nowTemp.php'
                ?>°C</p>
            <h3 class="label">Temperature</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="top-box top-box-b">
            <p class="values"><i class="fas fa-tint"></i><br>
                <?php 
                    include 'sql_nowHumid.php'
                ?>%</p>
            <h3 class="label">Humidity</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase"><div class="graph" id="line_chart"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

sqlnowTemp.php

```php
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT temperatur FROM setest ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $english_format_number = number_format($row["temperatur"], 2);
    }
} else {
    echo "--.--";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And another extra question: Is it possible to use one global timer on multiple requests/numbers?

Comment: Take a look at [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: Well, how do you write out the code for using that with my files? 
Can anyone elaborate with some example code?

Comment: You have (at least) a couple of possible solutions - using `setInterval` as mentioned to fire ajax requests every X seconds ( long polling ) or, my preferred option, would be `server sent events`

Answer (score 0):

Further to the previous comment regarding `Server Sent Events` I have quickly cobbled together a demo that could be modified to suit your needs quite easily.

The PHP portion of the answer is the endpoint to which you connect using javascript. The PHP script runs in an infinite loop and will query your db every 5 ( or whatever ) seconds. The Javascript code, within your`index.php` file, connect sonce and then `listens` for messages coming from the server. How you process those messages is entirely up to you to suit the needs of your app, here they are simply written to screen.

The HTML (very basic client)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8' />
        <title>Updates from mySQL server!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='results'></div>
        <script>
        
            const message=(data)=>{
                let div=document.createElement('div');
                    div.textContent=data;
                document.getElementById('results').appendChild( div )
            }
            
        
            let sse = new EventSource('sqlnowTemp.php');
                sse.addEventListener('temperature-reading',e=>{
                    message(e.data);
                    console.info(e.type)
                });
                sse.addEventListener('error',e=>{
                    console.warn(e)
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP server ( sqlnowTemp.php )

```
<?php
    # sqlnowTemp.php
    
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
    
    
    # Add your db connection
    /*
    
    $dbport = 3306;
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpwd = 'xxx';
    $dbname = 'xxx';
    
    mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
    $db = $mysqli = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
    
    */
    $sleep=5; # 5 seconds 
    $evt='temperature-reading';
    
    
    function sse( $evtname='sse', $data=null, $retry=1000 ){
        if( !is_null( $data ) ){
            echo "event:".$evtname."\r\n";
            echo "retry:".$retry."\r\n";
            echo "data:" . json_encode( $data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
            echo "\r\n\r\n";
        }
    }   
    
    $id=23;# for demo only!!!
    
    
    
    while( true ){
        if( connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL or connection_aborted() ) {
            break;
        }
        
        # empty payload variable
        $payload=[];
        
        
        
        # construct your sql command and execute the query.
        $sql='select `temperatur` from `setest` order by `id` desc limit 1';
        # actually query the db and fetch the recordset
        # and send as the $payload.
        #
        # here that process is emulated...
        # $payload=$db->query( $sql )->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
        
        $payload=array(
            'id'            =>  $id++,
            'temperature'   =>  mt_rand(50,80),
            'sensor'        =>  'ok',
            'error'         =>  'none',
            'time'          =>  date( DATE_ATOM )
        );
        
        # call the function to echo the data 
        if( !empty( $payload ) )call_user_func( 'sse', $evt, $payload );
        
        # actually send the output by flushing output buffers
        if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
        @flush();
        
        
        # wait for defined period before repeating loop
        sleep( $sleep );
    }   
?>
```

The result, to screen, will be similar to this:

```
{"id":23,"temperature":51,"sensor":"ok","error":"none","time":"2022-10-14T23:13:59+01:00"}
{"id":24,"temperature":68,"sensor":"ok","error":"none","time":"2022-10-14T23:14:04+01:00"}
{"id":25,"temperature":55,"sensor":"ok","error":"none","time":"2022-10-14T23:14:09+01:00"}
.......... etc
```